# C# use updated dll in Client System

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dll

I am new in C#. 
I have created a small windows application with a reference to a my other project dll file that is included in the setup file. I have forwarded the setup to the client. 
Now I have few changes in my other project dll. 
How do I update this Dll in Client System or How Do I create the patch for the my application with new DLL?

Please help?

NOTE:- I have use Standard Setup Project to create the Setup File.

Comment: Simple patch the dll :)

Comment: How do I create a patch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways, I can think of immediately:

1. If you have access to client system, just replace the new dll in the physical load path, assuming this is not a GAC dll and the new dll will get loaded at the runtime
2. If the assembly is installed in GAC then use something like this in the App.config:

   ```
   <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"      
    culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
   ```

Comment: How Do I use the App.config File for the GAC assembly file, and how do I include the App.Config file in my Setup file?

Comment: Default App.config would be <Exename>.exe.config, that would get loaded by default for checking the app settings, that's where you can use the above mentioned tag

Comment: Thanks, Will Check and Let u know

Comment: Check the following link for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx